# How would you solve this data parsing problem?

Tags: c#, f#, protocols, network-protocols

We are implementing an emulator for a piece of hardware that
is being developed at the same time. The idea is to give 3rd parties
a software solution to test their client software and give the hardware
developers a reference point to implement their firmware.

The people who wrote the protocol for the hardware used a custom
version of SUN XDR called INCA_XDR. It's a tool to serialize and
de-serialize messages. It's written in C and we want to avoid any
native code so we are parsing the protocol data manually.

The protocol is by nature rather complex and the data packets
can have many different structures, but it always has the same global structure:

> [HEAD] [INTRO] [DATA] [TAIL]

```
[HEAD] =
    byte sync 0x03
    byte length X       [MSB]       X = length of [HEADER] + [INTRO] + [DATA]
    byte length X       [LSB]       X = length of [HEADER] + [INTRO] + [DATA]
    byte check X        [MSB]       X = crc of [INTRO] [DATA]
    byte check X        [LSB]       X = crc of [INTRO] [DATA]
    byte headercheck X              X = XOR over [SYNC] [LENGTH] [CHECK]

[INTRO]
    byte version 0x03
    byte address X                  X = 0 for point-to-point, 1-254 for specific controller, 255 = broadcast
    byte sequence X                 X = sequence number
    byte group X        [MSB]       X = The category of the message
    byte group X        [LSB]       X = The category of the message
    byte type X         [MSB]       X = The id of the message
    byte type X         [LSB]       X = The id of the message

[DATA] =
    The actual data for the specified message,
    this format really differs a lot.

    It always starts with a DRCode which is one byte.
    It more or less specifies the general structure of
    the data, but even within the same structure the data
    can mean many different things and have different lengths.
    (I think this is an artifact of the INCA_XDR tool)

[TAIL] =
    byte 0x0D
```

As you can see there is a lot of overhead data, but this is because
the protocol needs to work with both RS232 (point-to-multipoint) and TCP/IP (p2p).

```
    name        size    value
    drcode      1       1   
    name        8               contains a name that can be used as a file name (only alphanumeric characters allowed)
    timestamp   14              yyyymmddhhmmss  contains timestamp of bitmap library
    size        4               size of bitmap library to be loaded
    options     1               currently no options
```

Or it might have an entirely different structure:

```
    name        size    value
    drcode      1       2   
    lastblock   1       0 - 1   1 indicates last block. Firmware can be stored
    blocknumber 2               Indicates block of firmware
    blocksize   2       N       size of block to load
    blockdata   N               data of block of firmware
```

Sometimes it's just a DRCode and no additional data.

Based on the group and the type field, the emulator
needs to perform certain actions. So first we look at those
two fields and based on that we know what to expect of the data
and have to parse it properly.

Then the response data needs to be generated which again has
many different data structures. Some messages simply generate
an ACK or NACK message, while others generate a real reply with data.

We decided to break things up in small pieces.

First of all there is the IDataProcessor.

Classes implementing this interface are responsible
for validating raw data and generating instances of the Message class.
They are not responsible for commmunication, they are simply passed a byte[]

Raw data validation means checking the header for checksum, crc and length errors.

The resulting message gets passed to a class that implements IMessageProcessor.
Even if the raw data was considered invalid, because the IDataProcessor has no
notion of response messages or anything else, all it does is validate the raw data.

To inform the IMessageProcessor about errors, some additional properties have been added
to the Message class:

```
bool nakError = false;
bool tailError = false;
bool crcError = false;
bool headerError = false;
bool lengthError = false;
```

They are not related to the protocol and only exist for the IMessageProcessor

The IMessageProcessor is where the real work is done.
Because of all the different message groups and types I decided to
use F# to implement the IMessageProcessor interface because pattern matching
seemed like a good way to avoid lots of nested if/else and caste statements.
(I have no prior experience with F# or even functional languages other than LINQ and SQL)

The IMessageProcessor analyzes the data and decides what methods it should call
on the IHardwareController. It might seem redundant to have IHardwareController,
but we want to be able to swap it out with a different implementation
and not be forced to use F# either. The current implementation is a WPF windows,
but it might be a Cocoa# window or simply a console for example.

The IHardwareController is also responsible for managing state because
the developers should be able to manipulate hardware parameters and errors through the user interface.

So once the IMessageProcessor has called the correct methods on IHardwareController,
it has to generate the response Message. Again... the data in these response messages
can have many different structures.

Eventually an IDataFactory is used to convert the Message to raw protocol data
ready to be sent to whatever class is responsible for communication.
(Additional encapsulation of the data might be required for example)

This is nothing "hard" about writing this code, but all the different
commands and data structures require lots and lots of code and there are few
things we can reuse. (At least as far as I can see now, hoping someone can prove me wrong)

This is the first time I use F#, so I'm actually learning as I go. The code below is far from finished
and probably looks like a giant mess. It only implements a handful of all the messages in the protocol
and I can tell you there are lots and lots of them. So this file is going to get huge!

Important to know: the byte order is reversed over the wire (historical reasons)

```
module Arendee.Hardware.MessageProcessors

open System;
open System.Collections
open Arendee.Hardware.Extenders
open Arendee.Hardware.Interfaces
open System.ComponentModel.Composition
open System.Threading
open System.Text

let VPL_NOERROR = (uint16)0
let VPL_CHECKSUM = (uint16)1
let VPL_FRAMELENGTH = (uint16)2
let VPL_OUTOFSEQUENCE = (uint16)3
let VPL_GROUPNOTSUPPORTED = (uint16)4
let VPL_REQUESTNOTSUPPORTED = (uint16)5
let VPL_EXISTS = (uint16)6
let VPL_INVALID = (uint16)7
let VPL_TYPERROR = (uint16)8
let VPL_NOTLOADING = (uint16)9
let VPL_NOTFOUND = (uint16)10
let VPL_OUTOFMEM = (uint16)11
let VPL_INUSE = (uint16)12
let VPL_SIZE = (uint16)13
let VPL_BUSY = (uint16)14
let SYNC_BYTE = (byte)0xE3
let TAIL_BYTE = (byte)0x0D
let MESSAGE_GROUP_VERSION = 3uy
let MESSAGE_GROUP = 701us


[<Export(typeof<IMessageProcessor>)>]
type public StandardMessageProcessor() = class
    let mutable controller : IHardwareController = null               

    interface IMessageProcessor with
        member this.ProcessMessage m : Message = 
            printfn "%A" controller.Status
            controller.Status <- ControllerStatusExtender.DisableBit(controller.Status,ControllerStatus.Nak)

            match m with
            | m when m.LengthError -> this.nakResponse(m,VPL_FRAMELENGTH)
            | m when m.CrcError -> this.nakResponse(m,VPL_CHECKSUM)
            | m when m.HeaderError -> this.nakResponse(m,VPL_CHECKSUM)
            | m -> this.processValidMessage m
            | _ -> null      

        member public x.HardwareController
            with get () = controller
            and set y = controller <- y                 
    end

    member private this.processValidMessage (m : Message) =
        match m.Intro.MessageGroup with
        | 701us -> this.processDefaultGroupMessage(m);
        | _ -> this.nakResponse(m, VPL_GROUPNOTSUPPORTED);

    member private this.processDefaultGroupMessage(m : Message) =
        match m.Intro.MessageType with
        | (1us) -> this.firmwareVersionListResponse(m)                        //ListFirmwareVersions              0
        | (2us) -> this.StartLoadingFirmwareVersion(m)                     //StartLoadingFirmwareVersion       1
        | (3us) -> this.LoadFirmwareVersionBlock(m)                     //LoadFirmwareVersionBlock          2
        | (4us) -> this.nakResponse(m, VPL_FRAMELENGTH)                       //RemoveFirmwareVersion             3
        | (5us) -> this.nakResponse(m, VPL_FRAMELENGTH)                       //ActivateFirmwareVersion           3        
        | (12us) -> this.nakResponse(m,VPL_FRAMELENGTH)                       //StartLoadingBitmapLibrary         2
        | (13us) -> this.nakResponse(m,VPL_FRAMELENGTH)                       //LoadBitmapLibraryBlock            2        
        | (21us) -> this.nakResponse(m, VPL_FRAMELENGTH)                      //ListFonts                         0
        | (22us) -> this.nakResponse(m, VPL_FRAMELENGTH)                      //LoadFont                          4
        | (23us) -> this.nakResponse(m, VPL_FRAMELENGTH)                      //RemoveFont                        3
        | (24us) -> this.nakResponse(m, VPL_FRAMELENGTH)                      //SetDefaultFont                    3         
        | (31us) -> this.nakResponse(m, VPL_FRAMELENGTH)                      //ListParameterSets                 0
        | (32us) -> this.nakResponse(m, VPL_FRAMELENGTH)                      //LoadParameterSets                 4
        | (33us) -> this.nakResponse(m, VPL_FRAMELENGTH)                      //RemoveParameterSet                3
        | (34us) -> this.nakResponse(m, VPL_FRAMELENGTH)                      //ActivateParameterSet              3
        | (35us) -> this.nakResponse(m, VPL_FRAMELENGTH)                      //GetParameterSet                   3        
        | (41us) -> this.nakResponse(m, VPL_FRAMELENGTH)                      //StartSelfTest                     0
        | (42us) -> this.returnStatus(m)                                      //GetStatus                         0
        | (43us) -> this.nakResponse(m, VPL_FRAMELENGTH)                      //GetStatusDetail                   0
        | (44us) -> this.ResetStatus(m)                     //ResetStatus                       5
        | (45us) -> this.nakResponse(m, VPL_FRAMELENGTH)                      //SetDateTime                       6
        | (46us) -> this.nakResponse(m, VPL_FRAMELENGTH)                      //GetDateTime                       0
        | _ -> this.nakResponse(m, VPL_REQUESTNOTSUPPORTED)



    (* The various responses follow *)

    //Generate a NAK response
    member private this.nakResponse (message : Message , error) =
        controller.Status <- controller.Status ||| ControllerStatus.Nak
        let intro = new MessageIntro()
        intro.MessageGroupVersion <- MESSAGE_GROUP_VERSION
        intro.Address <- message.Intro.Address
        intro.SequenceNumber <- this.setHigh(message.Intro.SequenceNumber)
        intro.MessageGroup <- MESSAGE_GROUP
        intro.MessageType <- 130us
        let errorBytes = UShortExtender.ToIntelOrderedByteArray(error)
        let data = Array.zero_create(5)
        let x = this.getStatusBytes
        let y = this.getStatusBytes
        data.[0] <- 7uy
        data.[1..2] <- this.getStatusBytes
        data.[3..4] <- errorBytes      
        let header = this.buildHeader intro data
        let message = new Message()
        message.Header <- header
        message.Intro <- intro
        message.Tail <- TAIL_BYTE
        message.Data <- data
        message   

    //Generate an ACK response
    member private this.ackResponse (message : Message) =   
        let intro = new MessageIntro()
        intro.MessageGroupVersion <- MESSAGE_GROUP_VERSION
        intro.Address <- message.Intro.Address
        intro.SequenceNumber <- this.setHigh(message.Intro.SequenceNumber)
        intro.MessageGroup <- MESSAGE_GROUP
        intro.MessageType <- 129us
        let data = Array.zero_create(3);
        data.[0] <- 0x05uy
        data.[1..2] <- this.getStatusBytes
        let header = this.buildHeader intro data
        message.Header <- header
        message.Intro <- intro
        message.Tail <- TAIL_BYTE
        message.Data <- data
        message        

    //Generate a ReturnFirmwareVersionList
    member private this.firmwareVersionListResponse (message : Message) =
        //Validation
        if message.Data.[0] <> 0x00uy then
           this.nakResponse(message,VPL_INVALID)
        else
            let intro = new MessageIntro()
            intro.MessageGroupVersion <- MESSAGE_GROUP_VERSION
            intro.Address <- message.Intro.Address
            intro.SequenceNumber <- this.setHigh(message.Intro.SequenceNumber)
            intro.MessageGroup <- MESSAGE_GROUP
            intro.MessageType <- 132us    
            let firmwareVersions = controller.ReturnFirmwareVersionList();
            let firmwareVersionBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes((uint16)firmwareVersions.Count) |> Array.rev

            //Create the data
            let data = Array.zero_create(3 + (int)firmwareVersions.Count * 27)
            data.[0] <- 0x09uy                              //drcode
            data.[1..2] <- firmwareVersionBytes             //Number of firmware versions

            let mutable index = 0
            let loops = firmwareVersions.Count - 1
            for i = 0 to loops do
                let nameBytes = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(firmwareVersions.[i].Name) |>  Array.rev
                let timestampBytes = this.getTimeStampBytes firmwareVersions.[i].Timestamp |> Array.rev
                let sizeBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(firmwareVersions.[i].Size) |> Array.rev

                data.[index + 3 .. index + 10] <- nameBytes
                data.[index + 11 .. index + 24] <- timestampBytes
                data.[index + 25 .. index + 28] <- sizeBytes
                data.[index + 29] <- firmwareVersions.[i].Status
                index <- index + 27            

            let header = this.buildHeader intro data
            message.Header <- header
            message.Intro <- intro
            message.Data <- data
            message.Tail <- TAIL_BYTE
            message

    //Generate ReturnStatus
    member private this.returnStatus (message : Message) =
        //Validation
        if message.Data.[0] <> 0x00uy then
           this.nakResponse(message,VPL_INVALID)
        else
            let intro = new MessageIntro()
            intro.MessageGroupVersion <- MESSAGE_GROUP_VERSION
            intro.Address <- message.Intro.Address
            intro.SequenceNumber <- this.setHigh(message.Intro.SequenceNumber)
            intro.MessageGroup <- MESSAGE_GROUP
            intro.MessageType <- 131us

            let statusDetails = controller.ReturnStatus();

            let sizeBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes((uint16)statusDetails.Length) |> Array.rev

            let detailBytes = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(statusDetails) |> Array.rev

            let data = Array.zero_create(statusDetails.Length + 5)
            data.[0] <- 0x08uy
            data.[1..2] <- this.getStatusBytes
            data.[3..4] <- sizeBytes    //Details size
            data.[5..5 + statusDetails.Length - 1] <- detailBytes

            let header = this.buildHeader intro data
            message.Header <- header
            message.Intro <- intro
            message.Data <- data
            message.Tail <- TAIL_BYTE
            message

    //Reset some status bytes    
    member private this.ResetStatus (message : Message) =
        if message.Data.[0] <> 0x05uy then
            this.nakResponse(message, VPL_INVALID)
        else        
            let flagBytes = message.Data.[1..2] |> Array.rev 
            let flags = Enum.ToObject(typeof<ControllerStatus>,BitConverter.ToInt16(flagBytes,0)) :?> ControllerStatus
            let retVal = controller.ResetStatus flags

            if retVal <> 0x00us then
                this.nakResponse(message,retVal)
            else
                this.ackResponse(message)

    //StartLoadingFirmwareVersion (Ack/Nak)
    member private this.StartLoadingFirmwareVersion (message : Message) =
        if (message.Data.[0] <> 0x01uy) then
            this.nakResponse(message, VPL_INVALID)
        else
            //Analyze the data
            let name = message.Data.[1..8] |> Array.rev |> ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString
            let text = message.Data.[9..22] |> Array.rev |> Seq.map(fun x -> ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(x.ToString()).[0]) |> Seq.to_array |> ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString
            let timestamp = DateTime.ParseExact(text,"yyyyMMddHHmmss",Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture)

            let size = BitConverter.ToUInt32(message.Data.[23..26] |> Array.rev,0)
            let overwrite = 
                match message.Data.[27] with
                | 0x00uy -> false
                | _ -> true

            //Create a FirmwareVersion instance
            let firmware = new FirmwareVersion();
            firmware.Name <- name
            firmware.Timestamp <- timestamp
            firmware.Size <- size

            let retVal = controller.StartLoadingFirmwareVersion(firmware,overwrite)

            if retVal <> 0x00us then
                this.nakResponse(message, retVal) //The controller denied the request
            else
                this.ackResponse(message);

    //LoadFirmwareVersionBlock (ACK/NAK)
    member private this.LoadFirmwareVersionBlock (message : Message) =
        if message.Data.[0] <> 0x02uy then
            this.nakResponse(message, VPL_INVALID)
        else
            //Analyze the data
            let lastBlock = 
                match message.Data.[1] with
                | 0x00uy -> false
                | _true -> true

            let blockNumber = BitConverter.ToUInt16(message.Data.[2..3] |> Array.rev,0)            
            let blockSize = BitConverter.ToUInt16(message.Data.[4..5] |> Array.rev,0)
            let blockData = message.Data.[6..6 + (int)blockSize - 1] |> Array.rev

            let retVal = controller.LoadFirmwareVersionBlock(lastBlock, blockNumber, blockSize, blockData)

            if retVal <> 0x00us then
                this.nakResponse(message, retVal)
            else
                this.ackResponse(message)


    (* Helper methods *)
    //We need to convert the DateTime instance to a byte[] understood by the device "yyyymmddhhmmss"
    member private this.getTimeStampBytes (date : DateTime) =
        let stringNumberToByte s = Byte.Parse(s.ToString()) //Casting to (byte) would give different results

        let yearString = date.Year.ToString("0000")
        let monthString = date.Month.ToString("00")
        let dayString = date.Day.ToString("00")
        let hourString = date.Hour.ToString("00")
        let minuteString = date.Minute.ToString("00")
        let secondsString = date.Second.ToString("00")

        let y1 = stringNumberToByte yearString.[0]
        let y2 = stringNumberToByte yearString.[1]
        let y3 = stringNumberToByte yearString.[2]
        let y4 = stringNumberToByte yearString.[3]  
        let m1 = stringNumberToByte monthString.[0]
        let m2 = stringNumberToByte monthString.[1]
        let d1 = stringNumberToByte dayString.[0]
        let d2 = stringNumberToByte dayString.[1]
        let h1 = stringNumberToByte hourString.[0]
        let h2 = stringNumberToByte hourString.[1]
        let min1 = stringNumberToByte minuteString.[0]
        let min2 = stringNumberToByte minuteString.[1]
        let s1 = stringNumberToByte secondsString.[0]
        let s2 = stringNumberToByte secondsString.[1]

        [| y1 ; y2 ; y3 ; y4 ; m1 ; m2 ; d1 ; d2 ; h1 ; h2 ; min1 ; min2 ; s1; s2 |]

    //Sets the high bit of a byte to 1
    member private this.setHigh (b : byte) : byte = 
        let array = new BitArray([| b |])
        array.[7] <- true
        let mutable converted = [| 0 |]
        array.CopyTo(converted, 0);
        (byte)converted.[0]

    //Build the header of a Message based on Intro + Data
    member private this.buildHeader (intro : MessageIntro) (data : byte[]) =
        let headerLength = 7;
        let introLength = 7;
        let length = (uint16)(headerLength + introLength + data.Length)
        let crcData = ByteArrayExtender.Concat(intro.GetRawData(),data)
        let crcValue = ByteArrayExtender.CalculateCRC16(crcData)
        let lengthBytes = UShortExtender.ToIntelOrderedByteArray(length);
        let crcValueBytes = UShortExtender.ToIntelOrderedByteArray(crcValue);
        let headerChecksum = (byte)(SYNC_BYTE ^^^ lengthBytes.[0] ^^^ lengthBytes.[1] ^^^ crcValueBytes.[0] ^^^ crcValueBytes.[1])
        let header = new MessageHeader();
        header.Sync <- SYNC_BYTE
        header.Length <- length
        header.HeaderChecksum <- headerChecksum
        header.DataChecksum <- crcValue
        header

    member private this.getStatusBytes =
        let l = controller.Status
        let status = (uint16)controller.Status
        let statusBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(status);
        statusBytes |> Array.rev

end
```

(Please note that in the real source, the classes have different names, more specific than "Hardware")

I'm hoping for suggestions, ways to improve the code or even different ways to handle the problem.
For example, would the use of a dynamic language such as IronPython make things easier,
am I going at the the wrong way all together. What's your experience with problems like this,
what would you change, avoid, etc....

**Update:**

Based on the answer by Brian, I written down the following:

```
type DrCode9Item = {Name : string ; Timestamp : DateTime ; Size : uint32; Status : byte}
type DrCode11Item = {Id : byte ; X : uint16 ; Y : uint16 ; SizeX : uint16 ; SizeY : uint16
                     Font : string ; Alignment : byte ; Scroll : byte ; Flash : byte}
type DrCode12Item = {Id : byte ; X : uint16 ; Y : uint16 ; SizeX : uint16 ; SizeY : uint16}
type DrCode14Item = {X : byte ; Y : byte}

type DRType =
| DrCode0 of byte
| DrCode1 of byte * string * DateTime * uint32 * byte
| DrCode2 of byte * byte * uint16 * uint16 * array<byte>
| DrCode3 of byte * string
| DrCode4 of byte * string * DateTime * byte * uint16 * array<byte>
| DrCode5 of byte * uint16
| DrCode6 of byte * DateTime
| DrCode7 of byte * uint16 * uint16
| DrCode8 of byte * uint16 * uint16 * uint16 * array<byte>
| DrCode9 of byte * uint16 * array<DrCode9Item>
| DrCode10 of byte * string * DateTime * uint32 * byte * array<byte>
| DrCode11 of byte * array<DrCode11Item>
| DrCode12 of byte * array<DrCode12Item>
| DrCode13 of byte * uint16 * byte * uint16 * uint16 * string * byte * byte
| DrCode14 of byte * array<DrCode14Item>
```

I could continue doing this for all the DR types (quite a few),
but I still don't understand how that would help me. I've read
about it on Wikibooks and in Foundations of F# but something is not clicking in my head yet.

**Update 2**

So, I understand I could do the following:

```
let execute dr =
    match dr with
    | DrCode0(drCode) -> printfn "Do something"
    | DrCode1(drCode, name, timestamp, size, options) -> printfn "Show the size %A" size
    | _ -> ()
let date = DateTime.Now

let x = DrCode1(1uy,"blabla", date, 100ul, 0uy)
```

But when the message comes into the IMessageProcessor,
the choice is made right there what kind of message it is
and the proper function is then called. The above would just
be additional code, at least that is how understand it,
so I must really be missing the point here... but I don't see it.

```
execute x
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think F# is a natural fit for representing the messages in this domain via discriminated unions; I'm imagining e.g.

```
type Message =
    | Message1 of string * DateTime * int * byte //name,timestamp,size,options
    | Message2 of bool * short * short * byte[]  //last,blocknum,blocksize,data
    ...
```

along with methods to parse/unparse Messages from/to a byte array.  As you say, this work is straightforward, just tedious.

I'm less clear about the processing of the messages, but overall based on your description it sounds like you have a handle on it.

I am a little concerned about your 'tool flexibility' - what are your constraints?  (e.g. .Net, has to be maintained by programmers who know technologies X,Y,Z, must meet certain perf criteria, ...)

Comment: About the constraints:
 We want the core of the emulator to be cross platform.
 We never use native code, especially not C code.
 I've seen the way C hardware developers write their
 code, it's scary! Abbreviations everywhere

3rd parties use whatever they want to communicate with the emulator (via tcp/ip or rs232).

Comment: Would you mind explaining what you would do with the discriminated union here? I know how to define them but I don't see how they help me...

Comment: You said: "I decided to use F# to implement the IMessageProcessor interface because pattern matching seemed like a good way to avoid lots of nested if/else and caste statements" and I agree, but specifically making Message be a DU is the key here.  When Message is a DU, pattern-matching on Messages becomes straightforward, and I think that's the biggest win.  (How else would you represent 'Message'?)

Comment: I think I don't fully understand how to work with them.
I know I can create them but then I don't see how I can get the information out. I'll have to find a good resource because the book I got doesn't seem to do much with it.

Comment: See e.g. http://lorgonblog.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!701679AD17B6D310!172.entry and http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Discriminated_Unions for more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my 2 cents (caveat: I know no F#): You have a finely specified input file, 
even with a complete grammar. You want to map the file's content to actions. Therefore, I suggest you parse the file. F# being a functional language, it may fit the parsing technique called [Recursive Descent Parsing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser). [The book "Expert F#"](http://books.google.com/books?id=NcrMkjVxahMC&pg=PA477&lpg=PA477&dq=recursive+descent+f%23&source=bl&ots=pkrZIykmgL&sig=iCIYjID1aJII__oNzm1Jy48h6gg&hl=en&ei=rrb-SffmGcKZjAe-2fSRAw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1#PPA475,M1) contains a discussion of recursive descent parsing.